# If page doesn't load in a specific time, cancel request

Tags: c#, selenium

I am trying to load a page within a specific time. If the page doesn't fully load within that time, I want to cancel the request by initiating Esc Key press and execute the rest of my code. 
The below code doesnt work for me. In spite of having the button click in a try catch, I still get a error in the main thread from where the GoToUrl_Timed methord is called.

```
GoToUrl_Timed(driver, By.XPath("//button[text()='Book Now']"), 20);
```

```
private void GoToUrl_Timed(IWebDriver driver, By by, int TimeOut)
{
    TimeSpan tSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(TimeOut);
    driver.Manage().Timeouts().SetPageLoadTimeout(tSpan);

    try
    {
        driver.FindElement(by).Click();

    }
    catch
    {
        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        action.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Escape);
    }
}
```

Comment: Whats the error? which line throws it?

Comment: Session time out error, started off by the button click event.

Comment: but thats not in the try loop so no.. I wouldnt expect that to be caught by the try loop and yes then it would barf